Passport.js successRedirect doesn't load page, request keeps pending in signUp form
Im trying to write signUp proccess with passport.js local-strategy and it works and save user data in dataBase but it doesnt redirect me and keeps pending while the failureRedirect works well the successRedirect doesnt work
This is my passport local-strategy file:
passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
    done(null , user.id);
})

passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
    User.findById(id).then((err,user)=>{
        done(err,user);
    })
})

passport.use("local" , new Strategy({
    usernameField : 'mobileNumber',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
} , (req, mobileNumber, password, done)=>{
    User.findOne({'mobileNumber' : mobileNumber})
    .then((user, err)=>{
        if(err) return done(err)
        if(user) return done(null , false , req.flash('errors' , 'This number is already use'));
        const addUser = new User({
            name : req.body.name,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            mobileNumber,
            password
        })

        addUser.save().then(err => {
            if(err) return done(err , false , req.flash('errors' , 'Something wrong try again later!'));
            return done(null , user);
        })
    })
}))

And this is my signUpController:
class SignUpController extends controller {
  showForm(req, res) {
    res.render("SignUp", { messages: req.flash("errors") });
  }
  async postForm(req, res, next) {
    const result = await this.validationForm(req, res);
    if (result) {
      this.register(req, res, next);
    } else res.redirect("/register");
  }
  register(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("local", {
      successRedirect: "/",
      failureRedirect: "/register",
      failureFlash: true,
    })(req, res, next);
  }
}

export default new SignUpController();

My route file:
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", HomeController.index)
router.get("/register", SignUpController.showForm)
router.post("/register", RegisterValidator.handler(), SignUpController.postForm)

export default router;

